# Cannot enable wireless Ubuntu 10.04

Tags: ubuntu, drivers, wireless-networking

I have recently installed Ubuntu 10.04, however I am having trouble getting wireless to work. Ubuntu says that wireless is disabled, and I am unable to enable it. I have tried Administration > Hardware Drivers however the only drivers listed are Nivida graphics ones.

I am unsure what to do as I do not think the process is the same as searching for drivers for a windows machine.

Any advice appreciated.

Comment: Please give hardware details. At a minimum, the output of the `lspci` command in a terminal.

Comment: 02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101E/RTL8102E PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller (rev 02)
03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Atheros Communications Inc. AR5001 Wireless Network Adapter (rev 01)

Above are the appropriate bits.

Answer (score 1):

ubuntu 10 has a neat 'feature' where a lot of the wifi drivers that work on the Live Cd don't get installed.

The easiest way, if you can, is to connect with a cable and let it update the drivers from the ubuntu site.