# Why can I not connect to wireless network?

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-10.10, hp-mini

I have a netbook - HP Mini. I installed Ubuntu 10.10 on it and now I can not get my wireless connection to work. What should I do?

Comment: Is it only your wireless network that you can't connect to or is it all wireless networks that you try to connect to? Since this issues tarted right after installing ubuntu... I expect it is a driver issue.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cannot enable wireless Ubuntu 10.04](http://superuser.com/questions/159999/cannot-enable-wireless-ubuntu-10-04)

Answer (score 0):

See the information for HP Mini at 
[Ubuntu Hardware Support](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/HardwareSupport/Machines/Netbooks)

Googling for "Ubuntu HP Mini Wireless OR WiFi OR 802.11" will find several useful accounts such as http://diffperspective.wordpress.com/2009/12/29/hp-mini-note-110-installing-ubuntu-karmic-wireless-issues/